# html string encoding question in php

Tags: php, html, encoding, entities

I have a string that contains html.
How would I htmlentity the string so that everything except tags are encoded?
For example:

```
$foo = '<div class="link">Here\'s is a link: "<a href="http://www.example.com">Doors & windows</a>'</div>';
```

I want to convert it to

```
$out = '<div class="link">Here\'s is a link: &quot;<a href="http://www.example.com">Doors &amp; windows</a>&quot;</div>';
```

Comment: That'd have to be `$out = "<div class=\"link\" etc....` anyways, otherwise both of your versions are syntax errors.

Comment: Can you explain why do you need this? Because I see no sense of doing this. I know only 2 cases when htmlentities are needed: (1) When we want to make regular text or values of html atributes to NOT interfere with html language elements. (2) When there is a need to show some special symbols from different charset than page's one.

Comment: Well, the answer to your question is simple, I want valid html. My string contains html which may contain characters that aren't valid. I want the html elements to remain intact, but run `htmlentities` on the data inside of those elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code snippet shows a function that will load some xml (ensure that at least tags opened have a closing pendant and such, otherwise you will see / read some errors) and then applies `htmlentities` onto all text-nodes. I actually have no real clue for what you need that, but probably it makes you happy:

```
$foo = '<div class="link">Here\'s is a link: <a href="http://www.example.com">Doors & windows</a></div>';

echo text_htmlentities(utf8_encode($foo));

/**
 * add htmlentities onto the text-nodes of an
 * xml fragment.
 * 
 * @param string $foo xml fragment (utf8)
 * @return string
 */
function text_htmlentities($foo) {
    $foo = str_replace('&', '&amp;', $foo);
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadXml($foo);
    $xpath = new DomXpath($dom);
    foreach($xpath->query('//text()') as $node) {
        $node->nodeValue = htmlentities($node->nodeValue, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', false);
    }
    return str_replace('&amp;','&', $dom->saveXml($dom->firstChild));
}
```

output:

```
<div class="link">Here&#039;s is a link: <a href="http://www.example.com">Doors &amp; windows</a></div>
```

Comment: I was beginning to wonder if anybody was understanding what i was wanting to do.. This works, except it only works for xml, is there a solution for html?

Comment: @nathanjosiah which charset uses your page?

Comment: @nathanjosiah: Updated the code. The function expects a string with utf8 encoding. [utf8_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) — Encodes an ISO-8859-1 string to UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

First replace the brackets with another token, call `htmlentities`, then convert back.

```
$html = str_replace("<","***OPENBRACKET***",$html);
$html = str_replace(">","***CLOSEBRACKET***",$html);

$html = htmlentities($html);

$html = str_replace("***OPENBRACKET***","<",$html);
$html = str_replace("***CLOSEBRACKET***",">",$html);
```

Comment: Then you need to use an HTML parser, and run htmlentities on the text nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [html_entity_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) function